# Failing to add a label to parentView via code

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I just want to be able to add a label to parent view dynamically i.e just by pressing a button.Not a real world application just learning.
Here is cut down version of the method it executes but can not see the label.

```
- (IBAction)addLabelToParentView
{
    NSLog(@"button click");
    UILabel* label ;
    [label setText:@"test"];
    [[self view] addSubview:label];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize your label with a frame rectangle.  Try the code below.

```
- (IBAction)addLabelToParentView 
{
    NSLog(@"button click");
    UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 20.0, 280.0, 30.0)];
    [label setText:@"test"];
    [[self view] addSubview:label];
}
```